# Which PHP mcrypt cipher is safest?

Tags: php, security, encryption, mcrypt

So guys, there's plenty of different ciphers available - but which one is the safest to use nowadays?

List: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If unsure use AES (also known as "Rijndael") with a 128-bit key. If you have developed some kind of fetish about key size then you could fulfill your irrational qualms by selecting a larger key, e.g. 192 or 256 bits; the extra cost is not high (+40% workload for AES-256, compared to AES-128, and it takes a very *very* fast network to actually observe that difference).

Beware that, regardless of the key size chosen, the correct mcrypt cipher for AES is always `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`. This is because the AES standard refers to the flavor of the Rijndael cipher with a 128-bit block size. If you want AES-256, you need to use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` with a 256-bit (32 byte) key, not `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`.

AES was published in 1998 and adopted by the US government as a federal standard in 2001, and it shows no sign of weakness nowadays. Some mathematical properties were found later on, but they do not impact actual security; mostly, they highlight that we have some relatively precise knowledge on why AES is secure. No other symmetric encryption algorithm has received as much attention (by thousands of talented cryptographers) than AES.

Most security issues come from how the cryptographic algorithm is used, not the algorithm itself. Use a proper chaining mode, add a MAC, manage padding, and most of all handle the *keys* securely. If you got all of this right (which is much more tricky than what it seems) then it becomes time to worry about choosing Rijndael, Twofish or whatever.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper chaining mode and add a mac"  Are you talking about the  cipher block chaining mode variant CMAC?  Because there are probably only 2 people on SO that know what that is.   Also you didn't say anything about the use of an IV.

Comment: A complete course on how a block cipher should be used would far exceed my patience, and that of many readers as well. The point of my message is to: 1. answer the precise question which was asked, and: 2. to make the requester feel that the problem is complex and should not be addressed lightly.

CBC mode with a random IV encoded with the encrypted message, and HMAC, are "proper enough" in my view. CMAC is only a MAC; for an advanced mode which combines encryption and MAC, lookup GCM (Galois/Counter Mode).

Comment: Are there any GCM examples for PHP's mcrypt?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "fulfilling your irrational qualms by selecting a larger key"? If 128-bit key was enough for everything then why would 192 and 256 exist?

Comment: The 192-bit and 256-bit key sizes exist for compliance with inflexible regulations within the US Army, which call for three distinct "security levels" for cryptographic system (this made sense when these regulations were written, in the 1930s, because in the pre-computer era we did not know how to make an encryption system which was both very efficient and very secure at the same time).

Comment: @ThomasPornin Would you object if I added a edit specifying that in mcrypt, only `RINJDAEL_128` is AES regardless of keysize?

Comment: @ScottArciszewski: be my guest.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Thomas Pornin's great answer, you also must consider what you are trying to achieve in terms of "security" (confidentiality/integrity/authenticity/availability).

For every case, you'll need to address a few questions, like... Who does this apply to? Where and why is it being used (what are you protecting)? How long is it meant to last? etc.

For example, there's probably no point in really encrypting session data with a full blown succession of 256 bit operations when the data is really only meant to last for say 20-30 minutes. A secure 128bit algorithm would be near twice as fast or at least use loads less clock cycles and be just as (if not more) secure.

There's also no point in encrypting something that's meant to last a long time (like a confidential document or file, private key etc...) with a weak, short key method. You'd want at times multiple algorithms with some sort of authentication and proper use of padding. I have regularly encrypted and signed content upon request for clients using multiple algorithms (mostly twofish, AES, RSA).

And not to forget either (like Thomas pointed out), you can implement a secure method (or methods) insecurely. With the vast amounts of variants of each formula and the such, it can be tricky to actually implement something that is "secure".

Generally, something is as secure as the key is to unlock it. If I leave my car keys in the car with the car unlocked, the keys aren't secure and it's open for the taking by anyone walking past. Blowfish with a well dispersed 32 character key would be just as secure as anything else today. A 3 character key however could be broken in the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 3):

"The strongest cipher is AES-256"

From details on Bruce Schneier's website, AES-256 might, ironically, be the least secure out of the three key sizes 128, 192, and 256.  There are issues with the key generation in the 256-bit variant.

Comment: Incorrect, for general use as a cipher, there are no specific vulnerabilities for AES-256. The related key attack is mostly of importance if AES is used to construct e.g. a secure hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Some algorithms are better than others at different things - not sure what your criteria for "safest" is.

You certainly should not be using any of the DES based algorithms these days (assuming you have a free choice). AES (Rijndael) is the current standard for NIST and other bodies.

In general more bits for a specific algorithm means more secure, but do ensure that you use a initialization vector and do NOT use ECB.

HTH

C.

Comment: Hi, initialization vector - can you tell me more about that?

Comment: RTFM? There's much better documentation there and in the internet than I could fill in here.

Comment: +1 ECB mode is for suckers.  Although IV's are dead simple to use,  just make sure that no 2 messages are encrypted using the same IV and the same key,  so you could use the primary key of a table you want to encrypt.

Answer (score 2):

According to the NIST paper, RJINDAEL had a low security margin compared to MARS, twofish or serpent. If you really need the strongest cipher, choose one of those.

http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/round2/r2report.pdf

To quote:
"MARS appears to have a high security margin. A precise characterization of MARS is
difficult because of the fact that MARS employs two different kinds of rounds. MARS
has received some criticism based on its complexity, which may have hindered its
security analysis during the timeframe of the AES development process.

Rijndael appears to have an adequate security margin. The security margin is a bit
difficult to measure because the number of rounds changes with the key size. Rijndael
has received some criticism on two grounds: that its security margin is on the low side
among the finalists, and that its mathematical structure may lead to attacks. However, its
structure is fairly simple, which may have facilitated its security analysis during the
specified timeframe of the AES development process.

Serpent appears to have a high security margin. Serpent also has a simple structure,
which may have facilitated its security analysis during the specified timeframe of the
AES development process.

Twofish appears to have a high security margin. Since Twofish uses key-dependent
round function, the notion of security margin may have less meaning for this algorithm
than for the other finalists. The dependence of the Twofish S-boxes on only k/2 bits of
entropy in the k-bit key case has led to a speculation that Twofish may be amenable to a
divide-and-conquer attack, although no such attack has been found. Twofish has received
some criticism for its complexity, making analysis difficult during the timeframe of the
AES development process."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at the details, there's an article, mainly by me, on block ciphers at http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Block_cipher

To comply with current US standards, use AES, formerly Rijndael. Any of the other finalists from the AES competition -- Serpent, MARS, Twofish or RC-6 -- should be fine as well. I think you need a license for RC6, though.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use AES-128 since AES is FIPS approved. The strongest cipher is AES-256 (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256).

mcrypt has a modular design and new cipher can be added easily.

Comment: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES.  It's the variant of the Rijndael algorithm but with a block size of 256 (hence the name), as opposed to AES, which is the variant of Rijndael with a block size of 128.  If you want AES, then use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, and supply either a 128, 192, or 256-bit key.