# Using PHP mcrypt with Rijndael/AES

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, mcrypt

I am trying to encrypt some text messages using mcrypt from php and the cipher Rijndael, but I am not sure about the MCRYPT_MODE_modename (according to PHP's manual these are available "ecb", "cbc", "cfb", "ofb", "nofb" or "stream" but I read there are actually a few more). I have no idea what each one do or how to use them.

I read two things, that ECB mode should not be used and MCRYPT_RAND neither. They didn't explain why. For the ECB mode I guess it's because it always generate the same encrypted output for the same plain text (maybe this could be used for an attack), no idea about MCRYPT_RAND (mentioned by @azz [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108408/php-mcrypt-which-mode)).

My question is, *what mcrypt mode should I use, and it would be great to see an example of php code using* it because all the examples I found use ECB. The strings I am trying to encrypt will contain only ascii text, and variable length, not bigger than 500 chars.

Comment: Related: [Which PHP mcrypt cipher is safest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809855/which-php-mcrypt-cipher-is-safest)

Comment: Wikipedia has a good description of the different [cipher block modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation), how they operate and their strengths & weaknesses.

Comment: Check out [Cryptography For The Average Developer](http://www.slideshare.net/ircmaxell/cryptography-for-the-average-developer-1) for a great working implementation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ecb is the simplest and has weaknesses so it is not recommended (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).  cbc is considered significantly stronger than ecb. Some of the others may be even stronger than cbc but they are all stream related so cbc should suit your needs.

From... http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php...

- MCRYPT_MODE_ECB (electronic codebook) is suitable for random data, such as encrypting other keys. Since data there is short and random, the disadvantages of ECB have a favorable negative effect.
- MCRYPT_MODE_CBC (cipher block chaining) is especially suitable for encrypting files where the security is increased over ECB significantly.
- MCRYPT_MODE_CFB (cipher feedback) is the best mode for encrypting byte streams where single bytes must be encrypted.
- MCRYPT_MODE_OFB (output feedback, in 8bit) is comparable to CFB, but can be used in applications where error propagation cannot be tolerated. It's insecure (because it operates in 8bit mode) so it is not recommended to use it.
- MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB (output feedback, in nbit) is comparable to OFB, but more secure because it operates on the block size of the algorithm.
- MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM is an extra mode to include some stream algorithms like "WAKE" or "RC4".

I'm not sure why MCRYPT_RAND is recommended against but it may be because the system random number generator on many systems is not considered to be truely random. There are only two alternatives and they may not be available depending on your system and PHP version. From... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php...

- The IV source can be MCRYPT_RAND (system random number generator), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM (read data from /dev/random) and MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM (read data from /dev/urandom). Prior to 5.3.0, MCRYPT_RAND was the only one supported on Windows.

The code below is just a quick sample. It works but I can't attest to it's strength.

```
<?php

// Test code

    $objEncManager = new DataEncryptor();

    $sensitiveData = "7890";
    echo "Raw Data: _" . $sensitiveData . "_<br><br>";

    $encryptedData = $objEncManager->mcryptEncryptString( $sensitiveData );
    echo "Enc Data: _" . $encryptedData . "_<br><br>";
    echo "Enc Data length: " . strlen( $encryptedData) . "<br><br>";

    $decryptedData = $objEncManager->mcryptDecryptString( $encryptedData, $objEncManager->lastIv );
    echo "D-enc Data: _" . $decryptedData . "_<br><br>";

    echo "IV: _" . $objEncManager->lastIv . "_<br><br>";


/*
 * Note: These functions do not accurately handle cases where the data 
 * being encrypted have trailing whitespace so the data
 *       encrypted by them must not have any. Leading whitespace is okay.
 *  
 * Note: If your data needs to be passed through a non-binary safe medium you should
 * base64_encode it but this makes the data about 33% larger.
 * 
 * Note: The decryption IV must be the same as the encryption IV so the encryption
 * IV must be stored or transmitted with the encrypted data.
 * From (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php)... 
 * "The IV is only meant to give an alternative seed to the encryption routines. 
 * This IV does not need to be secret at all, though it can be desirable. 
 * You even can send it along with your ciphertext without losing security."
 * 
 * Note: These methods don't do any error checking on the success of the various mcrypt functions
 */
class DataEncryptor
{
    const MY_MCRYPT_CIPHER        = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
    const MY_MCRYPT_MODE          = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
    const MY_MCRYPT_KEY_STRING    = "1234567890-abcDEFGHUzyxwvutsrqpo"; // This should be a random string, recommended 32 bytes

    public  $lastIv               = '';


    public function __construct()
    {
        // do nothing
    }


    /**
     * Accepts a plaintext string and returns the encrypted version
     */
    public function mcryptEncryptString( $stringToEncrypt, $base64encoded = true )
    {
        // Set the initialization vector
            $iv_size      = mcrypt_get_iv_size( self::MY_MCRYPT_CIPHER, self::MY_MCRYPT_MODE );
            $iv           = mcrypt_create_iv( $iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND );
            $this->lastIv = $iv;

        // Encrypt the data
            $encryptedData = mcrypt_encrypt( self::MY_MCRYPT_CIPHER, self::MY_MCRYPT_KEY_STRING, $stringToEncrypt , self::MY_MCRYPT_MODE , $iv );

        // Data may need to be passed through a non-binary safe medium so base64_encode it if necessary. (makes data about 33% larger)
            if ( $base64encoded ) {
                $encryptedData = base64_encode( $encryptedData );
                $this->lastIv  = base64_encode( $iv );
            } else {
                $this->lastIv = $iv;
            }

        // Return the encrypted data
            return $encryptedData;
    }


    /**
     * Accepts a plaintext string and returns the encrypted version
     */
    public function mcryptDecryptString( $stringToDecrypt, $iv, $base64encoded = true )
    {
        // Note: the decryption IV must be the same as the encryption IV so the encryption IV must be stored during encryption

        // The data may have been base64_encoded so decode it if necessary (must come before the decrypt)
            if ( $base64encoded ) {
                $stringToDecrypt = base64_decode( $stringToDecrypt );
                $iv              = base64_decode( $iv );
            }

        // Decrypt the data
            $decryptedData = mcrypt_decrypt( self::MY_MCRYPT_CIPHER, self::MY_MCRYPT_KEY_STRING, $stringToDecrypt, self::MY_MCRYPT_MODE, $iv );

        // Return the decrypted data
            return rtrim( $decryptedData ); // the rtrim is needed to remove padding added during encryption
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: WARNING: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is the Rijndael cipher with block size of 256 bit, in other words, it is not the same as AES. Also note that PHP does not use the de facto standard of PKCS#7 padding, and that it does not handle keys very graciously (expanding and cutting where required). Then again, the random generator has improved.

Answer (score 2):

The ECB mode is not secure because it doesn't introduce randomness in the encrypted data. That basically means you will see the same patterns of the input in the output (i.e. see the image reported [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTux_ecb.jpg), it's an "encrypted" version of Tux, the logo of Linux).

The MT_RAND is not considered secure because it uses the random number generator of the operating system (the `rand()` function of PHP).

For cryptography purposes it's better to use `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` (read data from /dev/random) or `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` (read data from /dev/urandom).

The most used and secure encryption modes, available with Mcrypt, are CBC and CTR mode and are fine for general use cases. It's always better to use encryption + authentication (i.e. encrypt-then-authenticate using HMAC). For instance, the CBC mode without authentication is affected by the [Padding Oracle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack).