# Simple encryption on a string in PHP or Python and decrypt in iOS

Tags: php, python, ios, encryption

I know this question has been asked a million times but every answer I find is either incomplete or links to the AES256EncryptWithKey category which has been removed due to insecurity.

Basically, I have a PHP script that sends JSON data to my iPhone app. In this JSON data, I would like to encrypt a few of the strings that will be decrypted in the app. These are not super sensitive strings or anything, just price lists that we don't want competitors to scrape for their own programs.

My encryption knowledge is minimal at best. I know PHP has some key padding issues so I don't mind if I have to use Python or Perl to do the encryption. I just want the encrypted string to be base64_encoded, sent to the app, and then decoded to be displayed in-app. I figure I will just use a hard-coded key on both the server and app to encrypt / decrypt.

Are there any easy classes, code snippets, functions, whatever to do just that? Any links to other answers that are secure enough for this type of encryption?

Sorry if this was answered before, I have been searching for a day and haven't found what I am looking for.

Comment: How are you requesting that data from the server? An http request?

Comment: Yes, a simple "NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest" to get the JSON. HTTPS won't work though since you can just find the URL that the app requests and get everything without any problems.

Comment: You could turn it to HTTPS and make the application send some kind of authentication as a POST parameter on the request. Just define some complex password or something and on the PHP end, only send the data if that password is provided.

Comment: @manecosta I didn't think of that. I would still like to find a simple way to do this without using HTTPS if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

Turning it to HTTPS and using some kind of secret for authentication would be a really easy way to handle the problem.

Another alternative you have is to implement communication with symmetric cryptography using some kind of pre chosen key that is both on your server and also ships with the app. I suppose this alternative is vulnerable to some kind of reverse engineering of the app to find out what is the key, but will your competitors go that far?

I found some useful Links that you can check for both iOS and PHP.

Which cipher to use: [Which PHP mcrypt cipher is safest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809855/which-php-mcrypt-cipher-is-safest)

iOS proper encryption: http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564

How to PHP AES: [Using PHP mcrypt with Rijndael/AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400203/using-php-mcrypt-with-rijndael-aes)

If you believe your competitors will reverse engineer the app to find the key, your only alternative would be to implement some kind of asymmetric cryptography scheme to agree on a key for use on a symmetric one. For that you would need certificates for the asymmetric part. At that point I would just tell you again use HTTPS which will handle all of that :P

Comment: Edited - the iOS link you sent is only about encryption. Is there any such pre-written classes for decryption?

Comment: In the example code by Rob Napier supply either `kCCEncrypt` or `kCCDecrypt` for the operation.