# PHP equivalent to Rijndael AES encryption/decryption in .Net?

Tags: php, .net, encryption, cryptography, rijndaelmanaged

Is there an equivalent functions in PHP that will allow interoperability with the .Net Rijndael AES encryption/decryption? (The encryption .Net code is below).

Basically, if I encrypt in .Net can I decrypt in PHP and vice-versa?

```
string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

// Generate the key from the shared secret and the salt.
Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

// Create a RijndaelManaged object
aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

// Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

// Create the streams used for encryption.
using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
{
    // prepend the IV
    msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
    msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            //Write all data to the stream.
            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
        }
    }
    outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Yes there is. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can*, maybe, but I cannot in good conscience recommend it.

PHP offers two extensions that can, in principle, do the job. OpenSSL suffers from not being documented beyond function prototypes, and Mcrypt suffers from being an absolute *minefield* if you don't happen to know *exactly* what you're doing. I wouldn't use either if I could possibly get away with it.

If you do attempt this, you will need to implement authentication yourself. You will need to implement padding yourself. If you screw up, you will get no indication even if the library knows perfectly well it's been asked to do something absurd, for the most part it will (silently!) guess at what you meant and continue on (patches for much of this are available, but not yet in mainline).

Godspeed.

Comment: I am wondering based on the two answers and what I have done so far, none of which amounts to anything, if my approach was wrong way back when. My main site is in, will be in, ASP.Net. All that stuff works. I introduced PHP, so that my DevExpress mobile app(s) could communicate with the server. The call, "jsonp(strUrl, '<data>');", in JavaScript is painless to contact the server and PHP has easy support for json, but probably .Net does too. I already have .Net working, why not use it?

Comment: For whatever it is worth, I found this link, http://lukieb.blogspot.com/2013/04/making-aes256-encryption-work-same-in.html, which implements the Rfc2898DeriveBytes() method in PHP, albeit with two extra parameters. Personally, I made a mistake by introducing PHP, so I will just do a purely .Net approach.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger That php implementation looks promising. For those extra 2 parameters, did you try setting $c to 1000 and setting $kl to whatever integer you used with getBytes?

Answer (score 0):

As long as PHP and .Net follow specs encryption/decryption should work. You may check this topic for more info and examples [Using PHP mcrypt with Rijndael/AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400203/using-php-mcrypt-with-rijndael-aes)

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew says, once you get everything in the same spec, it should work.  AES is quite a well used algorithm so librarys in both languages should match up.  Any problems are usually to do with the password to key derivation functions in the different languages.  [This project](https://github.com/dchymko/.NET--PHP-encryption) tries to solve the intercommunication issues between .NET and PHP.  It implements `Rfc2898DeriveBytes()` in PHP using a pbkdf2 with 1000 iterations of HMACSHA1 which I guess is what .NET uses by default.

It is a rather simple AES string encryption so there is no authentication.  The padding issue is solved by using base64 encoding and rtrimming null characters on decryption so it is **NOT a binary safe implementation**.  I take no credit or responsibility for this code, nor have I tested it between the different environments, but I feel it could help someone fill in the gaps.